# Exported variable always returns as 'false'

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, boolean, discord.js

Forgive me if "exported" isn't quite the right terminology here. I'm using javascript and discord.js to make a command handler for my bot which reads commands as individual files in a folder, it's been working fine until now, I'm trying to make a command which allows you to "lock" bot commands to a specific channel, the tech behind which I've figured out. However, for some reason the data within the variable `ticketChannels` which contains the channel ID somehow becomes `false` upon a command launching. I have ensured it is not being redefined anywhere, and have used *several* `console.logs` to ensure the variable is being correctly defined when it's being set to the desired channel, but somehow someway the command handler or something else along the way is turning it into `false`. I have tried several different ways of formatting the locked channel ID, including a single object array (because I have a point system formatted with an array and I can export and make changes to it inbetween commands just fine, so figured I'd try another array), tried setting it to just the channel itself and not the ID, have quadruple checked for any re-definitions anywhere, but nothing. I'm stumped. Any ideas?
Code for command handler:

```js
    function readCMD() {
    fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      client.commands.deleteAll()
    //deleteAll is here so that the commands list is refreshed properly everytime readCMD is called, as i have an update command that re-reads the folder using this function
      files.forEach(file => {
        if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
        let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
        console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
        client.commands.set(commandName, props);
      });
    });
    }

    readCMD()

    client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    const prefix = '$'
    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    let command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command)
```

The command, that I've tried running in the core file and out of the core file:

```js
 if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('$setticketchannel')) {
   const indArgs = msg.content.split(" ")
   if (indArgs[1].toLowerCase() == 'on') {
     var chosenChannel = msg.mentions.channels.first()
     console.log(chosenChannel.id)
     ticketChannels = chosenChannel.id
     console.log(ticketChannels)
   } else if (indArgs[1].toLowerCase() == 'off') {
     ticketChannels = 0
   }
 }
```

The execution:

```js
try {
   cmd.run(client, msg, args, bank, currentPoints, fs, duelon, ticketChannels)
 }catch(e) {
   console.log(e)
 }
```

And the command code trying to check for the ID:

```
  exports.run = (client, msg, args, bank, currentPoints, fs, ticketChannels) => {
    console.log("$GAMBLE:")
    console.log(ticketChannels)
    if (ticketChannels !== 0) {
      if (msg.channel.id !== ticketChannels) {
        msg.reply(`Commands such as these can only be done in ${ticketChannels}`)
        return
      }
    }
```

For clarification, every other variable I am exporting with the command handler works perfectly fine, I can edit and redefine them within and out of individual commands just fine. Additionally: it's not that the `if` statement is returning false, it's that the *variable itself* is becoming `false` despite nothing defining it as such.

Comment: I feel like your problem is cause by the fact that you are weakly comparing your condition. In the code `ticketChannels != 0`, you are not using a strict comparator `!==`which cause JS to try and cast your variable before checking the condition. I'd say try to replace your weak comparison with strict one and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Weakly comparing your type can lead to non false value  ( undefined, null, 0 ) to be interpreted as _falsy_. So an undefined variable would `==` to `false`. but would not `===` to false.

Comment: @Nicolas Upon trying to use a strict comparator the bot does spit out the error message upon trying to use `$gamble`, but no matter what channel I try to execute it in, it always errors, as the variable is still being read by the system as `false` and not the desired channel ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the problem today. Apparently in my `cmd.run(client, msg, args, bank, currentPoints, fs, duelon, ticketChannels)` line, because the `exports.run = (client, msg, args, bank, currentPoints, fs, ticketChannels)` line didn't include the variable `duelon` which *is* a boolean, it was confusing `ticketChannels` with `duelon` somehow. Including `duelon` in the `exports.run` line made it work just fine.